# Spring MVC integration tests with Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test my login page using mvc-test.
I was working pretty good before I added spring security.

My code is:

```
 mockMvc.perform(
     post("j_spring_security_check")
                    .param(LOGIN_FORM_USERNAME_FIELD, testUsernameValue)
                    .param(LOGIN_FORM_PASSWORD_FIELD, testPasswordValue))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attribute(LOGIN_PAGE_STATUS_VALUE, LOGIN_PAGE_STATUS_FALSE_INDICATOR));
```

Test class has correct annotations added:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:security-context.xml", "classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:test-contexts/test-context.xml" })
```

My filter is defined (in web.xml):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I try to add web.xml in @ContextConfiguration it fails, when I remove it I'm getting an Exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<405>
```

Is there any way to add DelegatingProxyFilter to test context with configuration defined in my security-context.xml to make it works? I tried few tutorials with injecting FilterProxyChain, but it is not working in my case.

Can someone help me with that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: dont think u can test security filters this way, as it is not a full-fledged http server tat is hosted, its rather just a way to resolve rls that spring-mvc-test provides. You might have to just rely on unit tests for the individual pieces in the authentication bit.

Answer (score 60):

**UPDATE**: Spring Security 4+ provides out of the box [integration with MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc). In order to use it ensure you use `apply(springSecurity())` as shown below:

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MockMvcSecurityTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }
    ...
}
```

**Original Answer**

I'm not sure what you mean by "When I try to add web.xml in @ContextConfiguration it fails", however, you can use Spring Test MVC to validate Spring Security. There is a very good [example outlined in the spring-test-mvc project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/context/SpringSecurityTests.java).

The basic outline would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:security-context.xml", "classpath:applicationContext.xml", "classpath:test-contexts/test-context.xml" })
public class MyTests {

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
            .addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }
}
```

The idea is that you `@Autowire` the `FilterChainProxy` (what the `DelegatingProxyFilter` delegates to) and instruct `MockMvc` to use the `FilterChainProxy`.

**NOTE** spring-test-mvc is integrated into spring-test-3.2+ and a separate project for Spring 3.1.x, so you can use the example fairly interchangeably (spring-test-mvc does not have support for `@WebAppConfiguration` and has to use `WebContextLoader` instead).

Comment: NB. The spring boot starter POM for spring-security does not include spring-security-test. I had to add it to my main POM to pick up springSecurity()

Comment: Boot uses the spring security bom which includes spring-security-test in 4.1.0+

Comment: @Rob I have spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-test and spring-security-test (4.1.0.RELEASE) with Spring Boot 1.3.5. If I remove spring-security-test then it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Yes you need to include spring-security-test. However, you do not need to provide a version.

Answer (score 2):

Add in pom.xml

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-snaspho</id>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

and use org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors for authorization request. See the sample usage at https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-test-blog (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2592)