# Integration tests with spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, integration-testing

I need to send a get request to the API, but despite having placed the **administrator annotation get error** `@WithMockUser(roles="ADMINISTRADOR")`. 

How do I send a request?
API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.instancia == principal.instancia.instancia")
public Validacao retrieve(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return validacaoService.retrieve(id);
}
```

Test

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")
public void testCRetrieve() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/validacao/" + id).with(user("daniela.morais@sofist.com.br")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
}
```

Log

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Test Class

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ValidacaoAPITest.TestConfiguration.class, WithSecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ValidacaoAPITest {
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        Fongo fongo = new Fongo("new server 1");
        DB db = fongo.getDB("oknok");

        @Bean
        ValidacaoAPI getValidacaoAPI() {
            return new ValidacaoAPI();
        }

        @Bean
        ActiveUser getActiveUser() {
            ActiveUser mock = Mockito.mock(ActiveUser.class);

            when(mock.getUser()).thenReturn(new User().setEmail("email@email.com"));
            when(mock.getInstancia()).thenReturn(new Instancia().setInstancia("instancia"));
            return mock;
        }

        @Bean
        ValidacaoService getValidacaoService() {
            return new ValidacaoService();
        }

        @Bean
        MatchService getMatchService() {
            return new MatchService();
        }

        @Bean
        PlanilhaReader getPlanilhaReader() {
            return new PlanilhaReader();
        }


        @Bean
        AtributoReader getAtributoReader() {
            return new AtributoReader();
        }

        @Bean
        AtributoDAO getAtributoDAO() {
            return new AtributoDAO();
        }

        @Bean
        UploadService getUploadService() {
            return new UploadService();
        }


        @Bean
        ValidacaoResultadoDAO getValidacaoResultadoDAO() {
            return new ValidacaoResultadoDAO(db);
        }


        @Bean
        Mapper getMapper() {
            return new Mapper(db);
        }

        @Bean
        UploadDAO getUploadDAO() {
            return new UploadDAO(db);
        }

        @Bean
        MatchDAO getMatchDAO() {
            return new MatchDAO(db);
        }

        @Bean
        ValidacaoDAO getValidacaoDAO() {
            return new ValidacaoDAO(db);
        }

        @Bean
        UploadOriginalsDAO getUploadOriginalsDAO() {
            return new UploadOriginalsDAO(db);
        }

        @Bean
        AtributoValidator getAtributoValidator() {
            return new AtributoValidator();
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    MatchService matchService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static String id;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testACreateValidation() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/validacao"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", notNullValue()))
                .andReturn();
        this.id = ((BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(result.getResponse().getContentAsString())).getString("id");
    }

    @Test
    public void testBRetrieveAll() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/validacao"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].id", notNullValue()))
                .andReturn();

        BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList) JSON.parse(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
        this.id = (String) ((BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(list.get(0).toString())).get("id");
    }

    //FIXME
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")
    public void testCRetrieve() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc
                    .perform(get("/api/validacao/" + id).with(user("daniela.morais@sofist.com.br")))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
    }

}
```

Comment: have you used WithSecurityContextTestExcecutionListener ? Can you provide the complete test class ?

Comment: You have a role typo, @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMINISTRADOR"), it should be @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMINISTRATOR")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the Spring security [Reference, section 10.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup) states that in order to be able to test the spring security features, you need to integrate the security filter chain in your MockMvc object, as shown in this example in the @Before setup method.

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CsrfShowcaseTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

...

}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, to be more specific, that is if you want to integrate spring security tests with the spring mvc test framework, if you don't want to use the spring mvc test framework, this is not required.

Comment: In previous versions of spring-security, this approach works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335200/spring-boot-setup-security-for-testing

Comment: SecurityMockMvcConfigurers does not exist in v5?! So, here is a better solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23665427/635891