# Trigger manually a FilterChainProxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've created manually a new spring FilterChainProxy:

```
private FilterChainProxy getCustomFilterChainProxy()
{
    List<SecurityFilterChain> securityFilterChains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
    securityFilterChains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"), new MyFilter1()));
    securityFilterChains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**"), new MyFilter2()));

    return new FilterChainProxy(securityFilterChains);      
}
```

And considering that I have a new HttpServletRequest, I would like to check the request against the custom FilterChainProxy. Something like this:

```
FilterChainProxy customFilterChainProxy = getCustomFilterChainProxy();
customFilterChainProxy.doFilter(request, null, (FilterChain) customFilterChainProxy.getFilterChains() );
```

But I'm struggling in correctly define the FilterChain used in the 3rd parameter of the doFilter() method.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write an integration test, using `MockMvc` with `.apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30652003/2433323) is a link to an post about integration MockMvc and SpringSecurity.

It is extremely useful, and allows you to test your login, and protected services. I often find myself writing/modifying the test before I try to see if it works in a browser.